# How to model scrunchy, rounded spiral?

Tags: modeling

How to model a spiral that closes in a circle? Like hair scrunchy. I know how to model simple spiral, but how to round and close?

[image]

Comment: Also you can model one part of it, and use an array modifier.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be very easily created by using the *Add Curve: Extra Objects* add-on.

[image: Render]

1. Open the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*)
2. Search for *Extra Objects* and enable *Add Curve: Extra Objects* by ticking the checkbox.
   [image: Enable add-on]
3. Create the spiral object through *Add > Curve > Curve Spirals > Torus*. Open the *Adjust Last Operation* panel in the lower left corner and configure the parameters of the curve. The most relevant parameter is the number of *turns*.
   [image: Create curve]
   [image: Adjust parameters]
4. Give the curve thickness by switching to the *Object Data Properties* of the curve and increasing the *Depth* property in the *Geometry > Bevel* panel.
   [image: Bevel]
5. Close the gap between the start and end segment of the spiral. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the two control points, then press <kbd>F</kbd> to close the segment.
   [image: Open gap]
   [image: Closed gap]

Comment: Big thanks to you, Robert, I did it!

Comment: Damn. This works really well. And I was wasting time with screw, curve ans simple deform modifiers... :). Thanks for posting this answer.